# jqTree to obtain tree from Json: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tree is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tree, jqtree

I am using `jqTree` to show JSON data in tree format using. while implementing Demo of `jqTree` I am getting this error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tree is not a function"

Comment: So whatever you are doing to include this plugin, there is issue. Provide relevant code you are using

Comment: the same code given on demo I am providing the link http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/#demo

Comment: But are you including plugin? If ya how? And how do you include jQuery? Only once?

Comment: Yeah I included jQuery 1.9.1 and yeah only One

Comment: Well but jQuery doesn't include any `tree()` method, so what about jqTree plugin???

Comment: both have no tree() method

Comment: Just read: http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/#requirements   All is explained...

Comment: I have done the same things but not working I donno why

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I have only included jquery once and jqTree using bower. But the problem is that this error shows up. Any solution is appreciate. Thanks

Comment: I am having the same error except I'm using `Dynamic Tree View Plugin with JQuery and Bootstrap` , none of the solutions in the comments help me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ajax, try specify the url for the JSON like this :

```
<div id="tree1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = '';
    $("#tree1").tree({
        dataUrl: '/doc.json',
        autoOpen: true,
        dragAndDrop: false
    });
</script>
```